# Cannot inject EF Core DBContext in an AZ Function MassTransit Consumer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, masstransit

I have a few consumers running inside an Azure Function and messages are being received and consumed by the consumers. DI works fine except when injecting a DbContext it crashes the consumer and produces the following error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: 
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection' from assembly 
'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

In my StartUp, the DBContext are registered and all my Azure functions are correctly injected with this DbContext but it won't work with MT consumers.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ReadOnlyMainDataDBContext>(options =>
{
   options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("ReadOnlyMainData"), opt => { });
});
....
builder.Services
       .AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(cfg =>
        {
                cfg.AddConsumer<MyMTConsumer>();
                cfg.AddRequestClient<IUpdateEvent>(new Uri("queue:my-queue"));
            }, "ServiceBusConnectionString");
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyMTConsumer>();
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
Type: System.TypeLoadException
Stack Trace:
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<GetOrAdd>g__BuildServiceProvider|3()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<GetOrAdd>b__2(Int64 k)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
at MyFunc.ReadOnlyMainDataDBContext..ctor(DbContextOptions`1 options) in D:\\Work\\MyFunc\\DBContext.cs:line 72
at lambda_method(Closure )
at DryIoc.Scope.TryGetOrAdd(ImMap`1 items, Int32 id, CreateScopedValue createValue, Int32 disposalOrder) in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\src\\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\\DependencyInjection\\DryIoc\\Container.cs:line 7849
at DryIoc.Scope.GetOrAdd(Int32 id, CreateScopedValue createValue, Int32 disposalOrder) in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\src\\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\\DependencyInjection\\DryIoc\\Container.cs:line 7834
at lambda_method(Closure )
at DryIoc.Scope.TryGetOrAdd(ImMap`1 items, Int32 id, CreateScopedValue createValue, Int32 disposalOrder) in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\src\\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\\DependencyInjection\\DryIoc\\Container.cs:line 7849
at DryIoc.Scope.GetOrAdd(Int32 id, CreateScopedValue createValue, Int32 disposalOrder) in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\src\\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\\DependencyInjection\\DryIoc\\Container.cs:line 7834
at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve(Type serviceType, Object serviceKey, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, Type requiredServiceType, Request preResolveParent, Object[] args) in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\src\\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\\DependencyInjection\\DryIoc\\Container.cs:line 309
at DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCacheDefaultFactoryDelegate(Type serviceType, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\src\\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\\DependencyInjection\\DryIoc\\Container.cs:line 225
at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve(Type serviceType, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\src\\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\\DependencyInjection\\DryIoc\\Container.cs:line 196
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.DependencyInjection.ScopedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType) in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\src\\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\\DependencyInjection\\ScopedServiceProvider.cs:line 25
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.Registration.DependencyInjectionScopeServiceProvider.GetService[T]()
at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.ScopeProviders.DependencyInjectionConsumerScopeProvider.GetScope[TConsumer,T](ConsumeContext`1 context)
at MassTransit.Scoping.ScopeConsumerFactory`1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at GreenPipes.Filters.TeeFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Send>g__SendAsync|1>d.MoveNext()
```

Other services that are injected as Transient or Scoped work perfectly fine with my consumers.

```
public class MyMTConsumer : IConsumer<IUpdateEvent>
{
    private readonly ILogger<IUpdateEvent> _logger;
    private readonly ReadOnlyMainDataDBContext _dbContext
    public AlertRuleRefreshCacheConsumer(
        ReadOnlyMainDataDBContext dbContext,
        ILogger<ITempBandUpdateEvent> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IUpdateEvent> context)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Nuget packages installed:

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.35" />
<PackageReference Include="Dapper.Contrib" Version="2.0.35" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core" Version="7.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="7.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.8" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.33" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue" Version="11.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common" Version="11.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table" Version="1.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs" Version="4.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.4.0" />
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As suggested below, downgrading MS DI to 3.1.5 did the trick.

Comment: "Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection'" ? Are you trying to mix 5.0 and 6.0 assemblies? or 6.0.x? What's the rest of the stack trace?

Comment: Yeah, agree with above, you're likely not using the same dependency versions and the proper runtime for AZ Functions. I'm guessing v4 of functions, you'd need v8 of MassTransit.

Comment: I'm on runtime v3. I have added the stack trace and the Nuget packages installed. The error message is kind of misleading. It's something to do with MT not being able to pick up the DbContext registration because injecting any other service that doesn't have a dependency on the DbContext for e.g. ILogger works just fine.

Comment: You can't use MS DI 6 with AF 3. I'd move back to the defaults included with the AF runtime instead of trying to use the latest (which you don't need anyway).

Comment: You were right. I guess latest is not always the greatest :)